# Как написать в личку автору вопроса, или прокомментировать закрытый вопрос

Tags: поддержка, статус-завершено, переоткрытие-вопросов

Хочу написать ответ автору [Формальный язык, близкий к универсальному](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/128476/224788)
Вопрос закрыт, в профиле никаких внешних ссылок для пользователя не нашел.
Хотя бы в личку, но хорошо бы нормальным публичным ответом.

Comment: Комментировать сообщения других участников можно после 50 очков репутации: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges В закрытых вопросах они работают.

Comment: @AlexKrass в комментарий хороший ответ может и не войти.

Comment: _Хочу написать ответ_ - что мешает написать ответ? если стоит галочка - это не значит, что нельзя больше давать ответы

Comment: @Grundy он был закрыт.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, забавно, похоже на баг, отображается только что редактировали в 12 году. или кэш, вроде обновилось

Comment: @Grundy ну да, год назад закрыли, 5 минут назад открыли, в итоге показывается дата последней правки - 2012 год.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, не, я как раз к тому, что сейчас обновилось и правильно показывает

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос (был) закрыт, потому что он довольно обширный, и потому что в ответах с большой вероятностью будет обмен мнениями и личным опытом. Это не соответствует принятому на SO формату вопросов и ответов.

Но давайте проведём эксперимент. Переоткрыл вопрос, можете отвечать. :)

Comment: ответ добавлен :)

Comment: Собственно, не является ответом на вопрос. :)